# Allow VM2 access VM1's SQL Server Database

Tags: firewall, virtual-machines, sql-server-2012

I have two VMs running on a Mac Server using VM Fusion 4. Both VMs are running windows 7, and I have SQL Server 2012 installed and data imported into VM1. Right now, I'm trying to figure out a way to access the data on VM1 from VM2.

I have tried to use `telnet %ipaddress% %port%` to test the connection. 
When I bring down the firewall on VM1, VM2 can access the database no problem. So I tried to create an Inbound Rule on VM1 to allow VM2's IP address. However, that just doesn't work out.

Here are my Inbound Rule Settings on VM1:

```
General: Allow the connection
Programs and Services : All Programs that meet the specified conditions
Computers: [Blank]
Users: [Blank]
Advanced: Domain, Private, Public (All Checked)
Scope:
   Local IP: 
      These IP Address: [VM1 IP]
   Remote IP:
      These IP Address: [VM2 IP]
Protocols and ports:
   Protocol Type: Any
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is that a typo or did you enter VM2's IP as the local IP in a firewall rule on VM1?

Comment: @lsmooth not a typo. Let me change that and see.

Comment: So I changed the local ip to VM1 IP, but it still doesn't work. Do I have to configure the outbound as well. Do I need to do anything for VM2 firewall setting?

Comment: Did you create the NICs of both VMs as NAT or bridged?

Comment: I don't know, I need to get a hold of the network administrator before I can take a look. He insisted that all I need to do is to setup the firewall.